# Escaping double quotes in exec java in Maven while executing through command line

Tags: maven

I am trying to execute a Maven exec command as follows:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.args="{\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"parameter1\",\"value\":\"1\"}]}"
```

The argument is a JSON string which I need to process in my Java program. But when the string is read by the Java class, the double quotes are removed and it reads as:

```
{parameters:[{name:parameter1,value:1}]}
```

I have tried different escape sequences like `\\` and `\\\`, but it doesn't work. I need to preserve the double quotes in the string.

Could someone please help me resolve this?

Comment: On which OS are you working? Have you tried to use single quotes instead of double quotes?

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.args="'{\"parameters\":[{\"name\":\"parameter1\",\"value\":\"1\"}]}'"
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use `&quot;` instead " (double quotes)